# CMAKE for opencv 3.0 installing don't find python3

Tags: macos, python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying to install opencv 3.0 on MacOS 10.13 and when I use that instructions:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules \
    -D PYTHON3_LIBRARY=YYY \
    -D PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=ZZZ \
    -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/python \
    -D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_python3=ON \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

The installation don't find my python 3 compiler and shows me that:

```
Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 NO
--     Libraries:                   NO
--     numpy:                       NO (Python3 wrappers can not be generated)
--     packages path:
```

How may I fix it to find the python 3 compiler? 
I've installed the python3 using "brew install python3"

Comment: you havn't install numpy

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to provide **full** paths.  Perhaps the `$VIRTUAL_ENV` part is your problem?  Installing it with a virtualenv python3 (e.g. with numpy) may be a completely different problem altogether though.

```
-DBUILD_opencv_python3=ON
-DPYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=/full/path/to/bin/python3
-DPYTHON3_LIBRARY=/full/path/to/lib
-DPYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=/full/path/to/include
-DBUILD_opencv_python2=OFF
```

You mentioned OSX with `brew`, so you may also be missing a slightly arcane path issue here.  On my system I have installed python3 with `brew`, the version I have installed is `3.6.2`.  So these paths actually need to be

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/
```

The Frameworks stuff is an OSX specific thing, but the `bin/` folder gets symlinked up to `/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2` whereas the others (`lib` and `include`) do not

#### HOWEVER

Why not just use `brew` to install it?  `brew info opencv` shows [`opencv.rb`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/opencv.rb), which **will** use `python3`.  That may be the path of least resistance here ;)

Note that OpenCV **is** "bottled", which means by default `brew` will try and install the bottle first.  It's generally better to install OpenCV from source (it gets compiled to your specific machine), so you will want to

```
brew install --build-from-source opencv
```

Of course this will take significantly longer to install!

**Update**: you may not have `opencv` available directly in brew yet, to get it you need to

```
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install --build-from-source opencv
```

More information on that and what comes with `homebrew/science` [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science#how-do-i-install-these-formul%C3%A6).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as the topic starter, and the way with *brew* worked for me.

The only thing:

`brew install --build-from-source opencv` installed opencv for python2

`brew install --build-from-source opencv3` worked for python3